# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  9pm UTC / 5pm EDT on the 6th - now!

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 6th at 9pm UTC, or 5pm EST on the 6th.**

[**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=4&day=6&year=2011&hour=21&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[**join the chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/406/physics-town-hall-chat)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 6th-9th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=physics.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/406/physics-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't participate in the chat, but I will answer all questions asked there or here at meta afterwards

Comment: Since sending in my availiblity my work-life has acquired another commitment, and I will only be around for the first ~15--25 minutes of this slot. I will accept questions ahead or after on chat or meta.

Comment: link to the transcript: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/793714#793714 I'll edit in my answers into the digest when it's available, if that is ok @Rebecca?