# Links/resources for the 2016 moderator elections

Tags: discussion, election

The 2016 Community Moderator Election is now underway!
Here are the relevant links and resources:

- [Election page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/3): Includes a brief statement from each candidate.
- [Official questionnaire](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/2016-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire): Questions that the nominees will answer as a way of demonstrating why they'd make good moderators. The questions here were selected based on response to a set of [proposed questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/2016-moderator-election-qa-question-collection).
- [Present (2016 September) moderators' thoughts on what it's like being a mod](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/in-2016-pre-election-what-activities-are-involved-in-being-a-physics-se-mod).
- [Election chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45927/2016-physics-stack-exchange-election): for discussion of election procedure and asking the candidates questions. This will also host our [election chat session](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/2016-moderator-election-chat-october-4-1600-utc).
- [**Main Stack Exchange FAQ on what it means to be a moderator**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq). Please read this if you plan to vote in the election. In order to cast an informed vote we need to know how being a moderator differs from e.g. 10k or 20k rep users.
- Town Hall chat transcript from the previous elections: [2011](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) and [2012](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest). Useful for background.

Please comment on this post to point out that an important bit of information is not covered in the links above, and we will track that information down and add it.

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta or in the chat room linked above -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).